# Trigger paypal onCancel event (OR Close the paypal popup)

Tags: javascript, jquery, paypal

I am using paypal checkout button to make purchases on my website. So far so good but there is one thing that i stumbled upon.
I want to trigger onCancel event in some cases. Is there a way to do that. Just like we do in jquery
$("#someelement").trigger('click');

If thats not possible then is there a way to close that popup if the windows/tab changes.

This is the documentation that i am using https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/

Comment: PayPal's onCancel event triggers when someone goes to PayPal's site and then clicks the 'Cancel' button - I'm not sure if (or how, nor even why you'd want to....) you could control that.

Comment: @CFPSupport No it does not go to their website. It stays on mine and then opens a popup. I want to know how to close that pop up

Comment: OK.... - guess I should have been more clear - - - the POPUP is from PayPal's site...... - and when a person clicks 'Cancel' (and PayPal closes the popup), the event triggers on your site (in your JS).....  I think it would help if you told why you want to close this yourself (as I believe you won't be able to close something another site controls...) - perhaps there is a better way to go about what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed by CFP Support, The POP up is on the PayPal so it cannot be controlled by us. But there is a small hack around. Actually the "Pay with PayPal" is a result of some js on our site. Particularly this code.

```
paypal.Button.render( settings, '#paypal-button');
```

What this does is that it puts an iframe inside #paypal-button div (or whatever element you are using). The POPUP is also triggered through that iframe. So if you wanna remove it, remove the content of #paypal-button. This will actually removes the iframe taking the popup with it.

```
$('#paypal-button').html('')
```

Now the problem is that it will also remove the Pay with Paypal button. So you gonna right some logic (depending on your scenario) to re-render it.

```
paypal.Button.render( settings, '#paypal-button');
```

Hope this helps someone.